# Jest : ProtocolException: Target host is not specified

Tags: jestjs

This is the first time I am working with Jest for Elasticsearch. I am using the following code :

```
  public static JestClient getJestClient(ContainerRequestContext crc) {

            JSONObjeect elasticsearchServers = new JSONObject();
            elasticsearchServers.putAll((Map) crc.getProperty("serverProperties"));
            List<String> connectionUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

            Set serverSet = elasticsearchServers.entrySet();
            Iterator serverIterator = serverSet.iterator();
            while (serverIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) serverIterator.next();
                connectionUrls.add(String.valueOf(pair.getValue()));
            }
            return buildJestClient(connectionUrls);
        }


    public static JestClient buildJestClient(List<String> connectionUrls) {
        final Builder builder = new Builder(connectionUrls)
                .multiThreaded(true);

        builder.gson(JestRichResult.createGsonWithDateFormat());
        HttpClientConfig clientConfig = builder.build();

        // Construct a new Jest client according to configuration via factory
        JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
        factory.setHttpClientConfig(clientConfig);
        return factory.getObject();
    }
```

I am trying to create index :

```
CreateIndex createIndex = new CreateIndex.Builder("inde").build();
jestClient.execute(createIndex);
```

but I am facing the following error :

```
org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified
```

My Elasticsearch service is running on all the servers.

This is my `connectionUrls` list of ips : [1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8, 10.11.12.13]

What I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing wrong was, I was providing only IP address of the servers, but it should be full address like :

http:// 1.2.3.4:9200

so I changed the line for adding connectionUrls to 
`connectionUrls.add("http://"+String.valueOf(pair.getValue())+":9200");`